# If I have a portable ubuntu webserver which I run ad hoc on my laptop and I want devices to connect to the server how do I do it?, how?

Tags: networking, server, lubuntu, webserver, moodle

I will be walking around campus with my laptop and it will not be connected to the internet. The ubuntu webserver is running moodle. I have fixed the IP address to static, 192.168.0.200. I want other wireless devices to connect to the webserver, as an intranet, using 192.168.0.200.

Being a network idiot:

1. Am I looking at an hotspot type of setup or access point?
2. Do I need some kind of portable router so the devices connect
   through that to my webserver? How?
3. I heard that I can create an
   access point with my laptop network card and ubuntu, is this true?
4. If I need a router do I need to do something like port
   forwarding?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be possible to setup a hotspot [https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-set-up-a-wifi-hotspot-on-linux/] on your machine to which other wireless devices can connect to. 

Since you are running moodle on your Linux webserver, other wireless devices connecting to your laptop would be able to access it .

PS: you wouldn't need a router as long as your wireless card supports hotspots

Comment: Hello, I've been trying to setup a hotspot in ubuntu but no luck. I don't get it; https://vimeo.com/286893733

Comment: My network cards should be compatible. Wireless Protocol: 802.11a/b/g/n/ac, Bluetooth Wireless Controller: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 - M.2 Card

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a USB wireless card(for hotspots) for your computer or use a router.

Most routers have DHCP servers which assign IP addresses to all the machines connected to them. 
You can set a hostname to your computer and have it accessible via the hostname for other devices. This wouldn't require you to setup a static ip on your computer . For example if it's user@hostname, you should be able to access your webserver at http://hostname:port . If the port is 80, your server should be accessible at http://hostname to those connecting to your router.

Otherwise you can setup a static ip to your system. You can go to the network manager, go to the properties of the network, change ipv4 settings and set a valid ip address.
The valid ip address should be in the range of the router DHCP assignment. 
If the router assigns an ip say, 192.168.0.104, then the ip addressess are in the range 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.0.255 
You can check this using the command `ifconfig` in the terminal.
Now to get the ip address of your router use the command `ip r | grep default`.
Set your desired ip address in the ip address, the appropriate subnet mask and the router address for the gateway.

Once you do this the other devices would be able to connect to your machine using your preferred ip address.

Hope I've answered your question.